# When I make check of leptonica, I got FAIL message

Tags: makefile, leptonica

I want to use leptonica. So I download and make and make check.
But when I use command `make check`, there is one FAIL.

How to solve it? I searched the similar problem in stackoverflow but I couldn't find.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////   iomisc_reg   ///////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////
leptonica-1.78.0 : libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 1.2.90) : libpng 1.5.13 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.7
Info in pixReadStreamPng: not stripping 16 --> 8 in png reading
Info in pixReadStreamPng: not stripping 16 --> 8 in png reading
Info in pixReadStreamPng: not stripping 16 --> 8 in png reading
Info in pixReadStreamPng: not stripping 16 --> 8 in png reading
Info in pixReadStreamPng: not stripping 16 --> 8 in png reading
Failure in iomisc_reg: value comparison for index 38
difference = 68.000000 but allowed delta = 0.000000
Time:   0.337 sec
```

I want 0 FAIL but the actual resuls are below.

```
   leptonica 1.78.0: prog/test-suite.log

TOTAL: 125
PASS:  124
SKIP:  0
XFAIL: 0
FAIL:  1
XPASS: 0
ERROR: 0

.. contents:: :depth: 2

## FAIL: iomisc_reg


leptonica-1.78.0 : libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 1.2.90) : libpng 1.5.13 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.7

Info in pixReadStreamPng: not stripping 16 --> 8 in png reading

Info in pixReadStreamPng: not stripping 16 --> 8 in png reading

Info in pixReadStreamPng: not stripping 16 --> 8 in png reading

Info in pixReadStreamPng: not stripping 16 --> 8 in png reading

Info in pixReadStreamPng: not stripping 16 --> 8 in png reading

Failure in iomisc_reg: value comparison for index 38

difference = 68.000000 but allowed delta = 0.000000

Time:   0.337 sec
```

Comment: 1. Examine the test code and output to determine the precise nature of the failure.  2. Decide whether the behavior is, in fact erroneous.  If not, then 3a. fix the test or suppress it.  If not, then 3b. debug the program.  Any way around, *something* is buggy, either code or test, in the configuration you've bbuilt.

Comment: John Bollinger - Thank you for your concerning.